# Put Parse.com JSON Objects into angular $scope Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parse-platform

I want to put Parse.com JSON object into angular $scope, but my code seems not working
I want to get `'title'` from the `'objects'` and put it as array in `$scope.title`

And this is some part of my js code:

```
main_app.controller('getList', function($scope) {
Parse.Cloud.run("MJSEvent_All",{}, {
    success: function(results) {

        var object = results['objects'];
        for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            $scope.title = [object[i].get('title')];
        };
    },
    error: function(errorObj) {
        console.log(errorObj);
    }
}); });
```

and for the html view:

```
<div class="row" ng-app="getParse" ng-controller="getList">
    <h3>Event List</h3>
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Speaker</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="x in title"> {{x}} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over writing the same variable `$scope.title` each iteration of the loop, so it will only end up being the last title in array

If you want an array of titles `$scope.title` needs to be an array

```
$scope.title=[];
var object = results['objects'];
for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    $scope.title.push( [object[i].get('title')]);
};
```

Or use `map()`

```
$scope.title = results['objects'].map(function(item){
     return item.get('title');
});
```

Comment: thanks, and I forgot to ask one more. How do I display the $scope.title inside my html file?  I have tried `<td ng-repeat="x in title"> {{x}} </td>` but it doesn't work

Comment: should work as shown ...any errors in console? What does happen?

Comment: no error shown in console, and this is really a weird one... using `console.log($scope.title);` showing the result in console but no result shown in html

Comment: i have edited my question, you can see my angular code and html code there

Comment: i have found the problem. it seems that i have to put the `$scope.title` outside `Parse.Cloud.run()`. Is it possible to put `$scope.title` array inside another `$scope`?

Comment: oh...I forgot...Parse is outside of angular core so you need to use `$scope.$apply()` to tell angular to update view when scope is changed. Put that at end of `success` after array is all created